# Developing REST service with / without Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, rest, maven, maven-2

I want write a simple REST service for college project. I can see two main approaches with Maven, without maven. Most of them use Maven.

Can anyone tell me what are the advantages of using maven with REST?

Comment: Maven is a build tool. If you know to use it, the advantages would be: time saving, increased probability of running the project on a different machine. However, Maven's job is not to help with REST services.

Answer (score 0):

You said: *"...I can see two main approaches with Maven, without maven"*... I don't belive implementing RESTFul services in Java is related to that.
Using maven or not is a way to work with Java projects in general, i.e., a RESTFul service or anything else. By the way, I strongly recommend using it (or gradle)

If you are about to implement a RESTFul service in Java try reading this article from Spring: https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/. You will see  three way to build it: with maven, with gradle or just adding dependencies in your IDE.

Good luck